# Javascript window.location redirect with url rewriting, no querystring

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url-rewriting, window.location

I have endlessly googled for about an hour, so please forgive me if this has been asked before.

I am using pure Javascript and do not wish to use jQuery.

**PREAMBLE**

I have an HTML form with 3 select boxes that control a search of items. When one is updated, a simple function reads each of the values in the select boxes and produces a URL that matches our URL rewriting standard.

```
http://www.example.com/search/select1/data1/select2/data2/select3/data3/
```

This is then used in a

```
history.pushState
```

to update the browser's url address so a user can bookmark the page right away. This works fine.

**PROBLEM**

When the user presses the button of the form, what I want is the function to read all the select box values, generate the URL as before but also load this specific URL so that the underlying database code can return the results for that search on the page.

However, when I use

```
window.location.href
```

it loads the page, but also sends the querystring from the form submission. This mucks up the database code because, essentially, it's getting all the data twice.

**EXAMPLE**

I choose 'A' from select1, 'D' from select2 and 'E' from select3.

This results:

```
http://www.example.com/search/select1/A/select2/D/select3/E/?select1=A&select2=D&select3=E
```

**SO...**

Is it possible to generate the URL in the correct rewritten format, then load the page without the querystring?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 function changepage(loadpage)
    {
        var theform
        theform = document.getElementById("searchform");

        var pageurl

        pageurl = 'http://www.example.com/search/'

        var select1 = theform.select1.value;
        var select2 = theform.select2.value;
        var select3 = theform.select3.value; 

        if(select1 != '')
        {
            pageurl = pageurl + 'select1/' + select1 + '/';
        }

        if(select2 != '')
        {
            pageurl = pageurl + 'select2/' + select2 + '/';
        }

        if(select3 != '')
        {
            pageurl = pageurl + 'select3/' + select3 + '/';
        }

        history.pushState('data', '', pageurl);

        if(loadpage=='yes')
        {
        window.location.href = pageurl;
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="form.asp">
    <select id="select1"><option>A</option><option>B</option></select>
    <select id="select2"><option>C</option><option>D</option></select>
    <select id="select3"><option>E</option><option>F</option></select>
    <button onClick="changepage('yes');">
</form>
```

Comment: Add `type="button"` on the `<button />` otherwise it uses its default value (`submit`) and submits the form.

Comment: Thanks. That sorted it. So, what's the accepted way of doing a search form like this with url rewriting but still allow people without Javascript to submit the form using POST?